# Lagrangian optimization leads to a contradiction

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, constraints

Suppose I want to

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & x\\ \text{subject to} & x + y^2 \le 0\end{array}$$

Graphically, I obtain $(x^*,y^*)=(0,0)$ as the optimal solution. I obtain the same result using the Lagrangian approach. However, if I change the constraint to $x^3+y^2 \le 0$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & x\\ \text{subject to} & x^3+y^2 \le 0\end{array}$$

then I get $(x^*,y^*)=(0,0)$ graphically but the Lagrangian approach leads to a contradiction ($x=0$ and $x\ne0$).

I am trying to understand why this happened when I changed the constraint. My intuition tells me it has something to do with the differentiability of the constraint. The function $x+y^2=0$ is differentiable at $0$ if we view $x$ as the dependent variable but not differentiable if we view $y$ as the dependent variable. On the other hand, the function $x^3+y^2=0$ is never differentiable at $0$, whether $x$ or $y$ is viewed as the dependent variable.

Is my intuition correct? Any tips on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the constraints are differentiable in both cases. You don't need to view them as implicit functions.

Basically, for the Lagrange multipliers method to work, the constraints need to satisfy some sort of regularity conditions (Wikipedia has a good list:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Regularity_conditions_.28or_constraint_qualifications.29)

The issue is that the second problem does not satisfy the regularity conditions, which in the case of only one constraint boil down to the gradient of the constraint not being equal to zero at the solution.

In its more general form (which leads to the Fritz-John conditions) the Lagrangian for the second problem will look like $L(x,y,\lambda_0,\lambda_1)=\lambda_0x+\lambda_1(x^3+y^2)$ with an additional condition that $\lambda_0^2+\lambda_1^2\neq 0$. You can see that (0,0,0,1) is a feasible point in this case.

Comment: why did this get downvoted?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry, I'm a bit lost so I will explain myself. First off, I don't see how the second constraint is differentiable at 0. Given $-x^3-y^2(x)=0$ and applying the implicit function theorem, we get $\cfrac{dy}{dx}=\cfrac{-3x^2}{2y}$ which is not differentiable at $0$. But I understand from you that this is not the problem, instead I must compute the gradient of the function at that point. In our case, we get $<0,0>$ as the gradient which does not satisfy the regularity conditions. Am I correct?

Comment: @Sadem. You are. It is true that if you consider the constrained as an implicit function, then explicitly finding $y(x)$ will result in a non-differentiable function. However, when wotking with Lagrange multipliers you don't consider the equation $g(x,y)=0$ as an implicit function, you work with the function of two variables $g(x,y)$, which is differentiable at (0,0).

Comment: @Sadem. By the way, I found that Wikipedia has quite a decent page on the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker and Fritz-John conditions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritz_John_conditions

Comment: @Serg, thank you so much again for your help. I have one last question. Is there any way to know in advance that the Lagrange technique will not work, other than geometrically? That is, suppose I did not look at the problem graphically before starting to solve using the Lagrangian technique. At this point, I do not know that the optimal solution is $(0,0)$, so given the gradient, I cannot know that it will be $<0,0>$ at the optimal point.

Comment: @Serg. Well, the classic Lagrange multipliers theorem for equality constraints explicitly states that the gradient of the constraint at the feasible should not be equal to zero. So you can find all zeros of the gradient and just check them individually after using Lagrange multipliers.